# Serializing object at specific byte index

Tags: c#, encryption, serialization

In `VS2015`, I would like to serialize a data table to a file, beginning at `byte 16`, since the file is to be encrypted and the IV uses the `bytes 0-15`. I have not yet found a serialization method taking an offset parameter, so should I convert the table to a byte array? There must be a cleaner approach. Here is one of the functions:

```
internal static void EncryptData(DataTable dTable, string userName, string password, string fileName)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        using (Aes aes = SetAes(userName, password)) // simply performs aes initialization
        {
            fs.Write(aes.IV, 0, 16); // writing the IV
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fs, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                dTable.WriteXml(cs, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema); // This is overwriting the bytes 0-15 :(
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Adding deserialization function, which throws the exception "Length of the data to decrypt is invalid"

```
internal static void DecryptData(DataTable dTable, string userName, string password, string fileName)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        byte[] IV = new byte[16];
        fs.Read(IV, 0, 16);
        using (Aes aes = SetAes(userName, password, IV)) // simply setting aes
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fs, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                dTable.ReadXml(cs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FINAL EDIT: The solution: Add IV bytes with File.WriteAllBytes and use FileStream filemode.Append in the serializing method(EncryptData):

```
    using (Aes aes = SetAes(userName, password))
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, aes.IV);
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {                                       
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fs, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                dTable.WriteXml(cs, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);                                                                                                                                       
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would be *really* surprised if that were the case. It would be very odd for `CryptoStream` to "rewind" the stream. Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem? (Ideally, without any datatables involved - just write a few bytes to the stream.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: It look like you are right, I have tested with a generic function. Yet when I try to deserialize the table from the file, I get an exception: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid. I'm editing to add the function.

Comment: Please include the stack trace within the question, and again, please post a [mcve] - paying more attention to source formatting to avoid extra long lines ending with large amounts of whitespace.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I'v found the solution and edited my post, thanks anyway :)